# custom spinner not showing drop down options

Tags: android, spinner

I have created a custom spinner with the following background. Now my issue is I can not use the drop down arrow (drop down arrow don't show options). Any help please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:left="50dip">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorGreen"/>
            <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="@color/colorGreen" />
            <corners android:topRightRadius="@dimen/x30" android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/x30"/>
            <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="50dip">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite"/>
            <stroke android:width="0.5dp" android:color="@color/colorGreen" />
            <corners android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/x30" android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/x30" ></corners>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="@dimen/x20"
        android:top="@dimen/x20"
        android:right="@dimen/x20">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/drop_down"
            android:gravity="center|right" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this is my custom spinner background  spinnerbg.xml



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90"
                        android:endColor="@color/spinner"
                        android:startColor="@color/spinner"
                        android:type="linear" />

                    <corners android:radius="0dp" />

                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right"
                    android:src="@drawable/dropdown" />

            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector> 





    Inside my style.xml i have done like this


     <style name="spinner_style" >
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinnerbg</item>
            <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
            <item name="android:paddingBottom">5dp</item>
        </style>
```

you can try this one it is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

remove this from your xml

```
<item
    android:bottom="@dimen/x20"
    android:top="@dimen/x20"
    android:right="@dimen/x20">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/drop_down"
        android:gravity="center|right" />
</item>
```

And add another button in your xml very next to dropdown. Give that button background as drawable drop_down.Then in onCliskListener of that button you can show/hide your dropdown list. Set adapter in onClick and provide this adapter to spinner so upon click it will create your drop down and as they are very close to eachother your button looks part of your dropdown.

Comment: for further assistance you can text me anytime :)